# Swashbuckle: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: c#, typescript, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I'm using [swagger-angular-generator](https://github.com/jnwltr/swagger-angular-generator) for a couple of months with success. After a git clean I had to reinstall with npm and since then it throws the following error on all nested C# class and enum properties:

> (node:14544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'match' of undefined at translateType
>   (\node_modules\swagger-angular-generator\dist\common.js:153:26) at
>   processProperty
>   (\node_modules\swagger-angular-generator\dist\common.js:44:27) at
>   _.flatMap (\node_modules\swagger-angular-generator\dist\common.js:19:53) at
>   \node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3543:27

If I remove the class it goes further and stops at the next nested object. This was working before and my C# code hasn't changed a while. I'm using swashbucke at the backend and generate a v2 format Swagger document.

What could go wrong? I was using v4.1.0 of the generator so I went back to that version but it didn't help either. So I'm on 4.2.1 now. The node script I run starts the generate method as `generate(jsonPath, outputPath, /*generateStore:*/ false, /*unwrapSingleParamMethods:*/ false);`

*Update 1:*

I've realized that I had a **SchemaFilter** applied on the generated openapi schema by **Swashbuckle**. Since I updated my project to .NET Core 3.1 (from 3.0) and Swashbuckle from 5.0.0-rc4 to 5.0.0 the SchemaFilterContext.ApiModel property isn't available. I've updated my filter changing `context.ApiModel.Type` to `context.Type`. Can this be the cause of the error in the generator? However, the generated json schema looks fine and shows up in the Swashbuckle browser as well.

*Update 2:*

Okay, I just simply went back to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0-rc4 using the old context.ApiModel.Type property on my schemafilter and everything is working again properly. So my final question is: **What's the equivalent of SchemaFilter.ApiModel.Type when upgrading from 5.0.0-rc4 to 5.0.0?**